# Create a cookie with a random value in PHP --> use that random value inside a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build an online store as a project, and every visitor to the website will get a cookie with a randomly generated 'seed' as a value, which looks like this:

```
setcookie('pagination_seed', rand(), time() + (18000)); //5 hours
```

Then I'll use that value to create a mysql query to echo out the products, sorted by the 'seed' saved by the cookie.

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    name,
    id
FROM
    products
ORDER BY 
    rand('$cookie_session_seed') 
LIMIT
 .........(php calculation to make the pagination work).........
```

The problem is that rand() cannot store a 'consistently random' value in the cookie session. Each page refresh will give the same user a 'new' random value, because the visitors will, by default, land on the products page, and according to how cookie sessions work, it only starts to work after a page reload.

What is a proper method to show fresh results after every x amount of time, per visitor?

For this project it doesn't really matter if all the visitors get the same seed (it would be better if they do get the same seed), as long as new and fresh results can be seen every x hours.

Please be lenient, I'm trying to learn about cookies for ages (I learnt php, jquery, mysql and css3) but cookies are my nightmare, I just can't wrap my head around it.

Maybe what I'm trying to achieve is not even done by using cookies. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: It seems you should be checking if the cookie exists `isset($_COOKIE['pagination_seed'])` before you set it again?

Comment: Yes @Nick, I do that, but it still gives a 'new' cookie value each time the page is refreshed. That is the problem I'm faced with ... (because the cookie only starts working after a page reload), so it's like a continuous 'loop' that basically never sets a cookie to one value.

Comment: If you check if it exists then it shouldn't be creating a new value just because the page is refreshed as the cookie will already exist when the page is refreshed.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I would recommend to use sessions to store the data instead of cookies. You can never trust cookies.